# Qual a tag correta para agrupar elementos em um aside

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Estou criando uma barra lateral para meu site, quero colocar algo como "ultimas postagens, rede sociais, uma especie de top mais baixados etc.."
ou algo mais simples "ultimas postagens" só :D ..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
mas estou em dúvida em relação a tag aside, li, reli, e ainda tó lendo sobre ela mas tó boiando..
é realmente a tag indicada para criar essa parte do site ?
é oque pode agrupar esses elementos, digo: "ultimas postagens, redes sociais" etc..
section ? article ? ul ? ...
vlw

sei que ela precisa estar relacionada com o conteúdo principal da página, mas não sei se oque eu propus esta relacionado com o post ..
exemplo: article sobre carros, mas meu aside tem ultimas postagens e redes sociais .. não parece relacionado, mas tem muito site que usa aside dessa forma, gostaria de entender se é correto .. obrigado quem ajudar

edit:O elemento pode ser usado para efeitos tipográficos como citações puxar ou barras laterais, para a publicidade, para grupos de nav elementos, e por outro conteúdo que é considerado separado do conteúdo principal da página.

tirei isso do https://html.spec.whatwg.org/ , se entendi bem(espero que sim) posso usar para conteúdos separados do conteúdo principal, como redes sociais, ultimos posts etc.. ?

Answer (score 2):

Esse é exatamente o propósito da tag aside, pode usar sem medo!
Geralmente, pra esse tipo de estrutura eu usaria as 4 tags: 
 
header / section / aside / footer 
para agrupar, respectivamente:
 
cabeçalho / corpo (conteúdo principal) / barra lateral (com links para navegação, etc.) / rodapé.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta:

`<aside>` como o amigo @IgorSantos disse é corretamente usado para esse tipo de conteúdo, a famosa "sidebar".

Sobre as outras tags:

`<section>` Usado para conter cada "seção" do conteúdo principal da sua página

`<article>` usado para um indicar que o conteúdo dentro dele é um artigo (post)

`<ul>` usado para criar uma lista não ordenada:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  </li>
  <li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Sendo que você pode ter obviamente um `<article>` dentro do seu `<aside>`..
É basicamente por aí... você pode ler melhor sobre as tags HTML nesse artigo:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list